# jsonb calculate the column sum() and select the highest value / select from (select(sum()))

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I need to select the largest value that results from sum()

```
SELECT
    row_data->>'companyName' AS "NOME EMPRESA", 
    count(row_data->>'companyName') AS "Count"  ,
    sum((row_data->>'bankMovementAmount')::float +0.0) AS "VALOR S"  
 FROM public.teste
 where abbreviation = 'BMO' AND row_data->>'bankMovementOperationType'= 'S'  
GROUP BY row_data->>'companyName'
ORDER BY row_data->>'companyName' ASC;
```

Does anyone know how to help me, in a select from (select from)

how to filter in cast exit goes into

bankMovementOperationType'= 'S'exit

bankMovementOperationType'= 'E' goes into

sum((row_data->>'bankMovementAmount')::float +0.0) AS "VALOR S"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alyTH.png)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "*how to filter in cast exit goes into*". Can you rephrase and/or give an example, please?

Comment: "*I need to select the largest value*" - then order by that, not by `companyName`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify it. You can also use [formatting](/help/formatting) in there easier.

Comment: Something like this, for example:```sum((row_data->>'bankMovementAmount')::float bankMovementOperationType'= 'E' goes into"+0.0) ```AS "VALOR S"

Comment: That makes no sense. You're already filtering for `row_data->>'bankMovementOperationType'= 'S'` in the `WHERE` clause, so it'll never be `= 'E'`.

Comment: yes, but it can be, 'S' exit or 'E' enter, if you filter by 'E', it only reaches 'E' or 'S'. If it is possible to filter in Cast, it would not be necessary in where:
```sum((row_data->>'bankMovementAmount')::float goes into"+0.0) AND bankMovementOperationType'= 'E' AS "VALOR S"```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "*it only reaches 'E' or 'S'*". There's no `OR` in your code.

Comment: I put an image above

Comment: ```bankMovementOperationType'= 'E'```  add money ```bankMovementOperationType'= 'S'``` remove money

Comment: Sounds like you would want to use a `CASE` statement to negate the outgoing money amounts. Not any filtering.

Comment: ```sum(sum(bankMovementOperationType'= 'E') - sum(bankMovementOperationType'= 'S'))```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either [a conditional multiplicator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE)

```
SUM(
  (row_data->>'bankMovementAmount')::float
  * (CASE row_data->>'bankMovementOperationType'
    WHEN 'S' THEN -1.0
    WHEN 'E' THEN  1.0
  END)
) AS "VALOR S"
```

or [two filtering aggregates](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES)

```
( SUM( (row_data->>'bankMovementAmount')::float ) FILTER (WHERE row_data->>'bankMovementOperationType' = 'E')
- SUM( (row_data->>'bankMovementAmount')::float ) FILTER (WHERE row_data->>'bankMovementOperationType' = 'S')
) AS "VALOR S"
```

Comment: Exactly that, now present the 'companyName' and the highest value, thank you!

Comment: Just `ORDER BY "VALOR S" DESC LIMIT 1`, otherwise keep your grouping by company name as-is.